# How to turn a bs4 findall() object into a string

Tags: python, html, database, beautifulsoup

Heres my code:

```py
with requests.Session() as s:
      r = s.get(url, headers=headers)
      soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
      sizes = soup.findAll(True,{'class':'product__sizes-size-1'})
```

I want to turn sizes into a string object instead of a tag so i can complete

```py
parsed_sizes = [item for item in sizes if 1 <= item <= 20]
```

which requires a string to compare
Right now priting sizes outputs:

```
[<span class="product__sizes-size-1">6</span>, <span class="product__sizes-size-1">6.5</span>, <span class="product__sizes-size-1">7</span>, <span class="product__sizes-size-1">7.5</span>, <span class="product__sizes-size-1">8</span>, <span class="product__sizes-size-1">8.5</span>, <span class="product__sizes-size-1">9</span>, <span class="product__sizes-size-1"></span>, <span class="product__sizes-size-1"></span>, <span class="product__sizes-size-1"></span>, <span class="product__sizes-size-1"></span>, <span class="product__sizes-size-1"></span>, <span class="product__sizes-size-1"></span>, <span class="product__sizes-size-1"></span>]
```

If I do `type()`  i get `<class'bs4.element.ResultSet'>`

Comment: Help us help you - share what you get for `sizes` now, and what you would want to get instead

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the tag text, convert to a number and then it should work.

For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

sizes = """[<span class="product__sizes-size-1">6</span>, <span class="product__sizes-size-1">6.5</span>, <span class="product__sizes-size-1">7</span>, <span class="product__sizes-size-1">7.5</span>, <span class="product__sizes-size-1">8</span>, <span class="product__sizes-size-1">8.5</span>, <span class="product__sizes-size-1">9</span>, <span class="product__sizes-size-1"></span>, <span class="product__sizes-size-1"></span>, <span class="product__sizes-size-1"></span>, <span class="product__sizes-size-1"></span>, <span class="product__sizes-size-1"></span>, <span class="product__sizes-size-1"></span>, <span class="product__sizes-size-1"></span>]
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(sizes, "html.parser").find_all(True, {'class': 'product__sizes-size-1'}, text=True)
parsed_sizes = [
    item.getText(strip=True) for item in soup 
    if 1 <= float(item.getText(strip=True)) <= 20
]
print(parsed_sizes)
```

Output:

```
['6', '6.5', '7', '7.5', '8', '8.5', '9']
```